# MySQL - finding average number in WHERE

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the average number of the sum of some rows according to a WHERE clause.  Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT SUM(rating), id
FROM rating
WHERE id=$id;");
```

So something like "sum of rows" / "number of rows returned"

Comment: You've got some 'string' left over...the final `");` looks unwanted in this context (even if it is needed in your program).

Answer (score 4):

[`AVG(expr)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg): Returns the average value of `expr`, e.g.,

```
SELECT
    AVG(rating),
    id
FROM
    rating
WHERE
    id=$id
GROUP BY
    id
```

(Edit: Forgot the `GROUP BY`)

Answer (score 0):

Is it not as simple as:

```
SELECT SUM(rating) AS sum, AVG(rating) AS avg, id
  FROM rating
 WHERE id = $id
 GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL actually has a built in average function

```
SELECT AVG(rating) as average_rating,
id
FROM rating
WHERE id=$id
GROUP BY id
```

If for some reason you really wanted to use the SUM, you could use

```
SELECT SUM(rating)/COUNT(rating) as average_rating,
id
FROM rating
WHERE id=$id
GROUP BY id
```

Hopefully not though!